# How to SEMI-automatically mount encrypted disk at log in

Tags: mount, encryption, luks

**Current behavior**: I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on an SSD and I use a separate HDD for my data. The HDD is encrypted with LUKS, but right now I need to manually open gnome-disk-utility and click the "unlock" icon to trigger the password prompt.

**The desired behavior**: After logging in to my Ubuntu account, I want to automatically receive a prompt to enter my password for my LUKS-encrypted HDD. I *don't* want the disk to be decrypted automatically at log-in because then the disk is only truly protected by my login password. I always want to manually enter the password, I just don't want to manually trigger the prompt every time I log in.

Any idea what settings I can use to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Give a partition such as /dev/sdb1, you can use fstab to automatically mount the partitions during boot stage.

With fstab you can automatically mount it using a secret key or do it manually and you will be asked for a passphrase.

Edit /etc/fstab and add a line with the following format:

```
    [Virtual Device]     [mount point]
```

For instance:

```
    /dev/mapper/secretdisk          /mnt/secret
```

Next edit /etc/crypttab. Here we are providing the LUKS device name, the mapped partition and the key file location (optional).  Since you don't want to automatically mount the partition you don't want to use a key file. Instead you should use the keyword none.

```
    secretdisk    /dev/sdb1    none
```

Reboot and you should see the prompt asking for the passphrase.